# Managing memory across multiple views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, ios5

I'm building an app that has a main view which consists of a Map View. A second view has some necessary configuration options (config view). I segue to this config view using a partial curl segue.

The problem I'm having is the state of my config view is not being maintained.

For example,

I will segue into the config view, make some changes to the settings and return to the main Map View. Once I return to the config view again the values are back to their default values. The value in question is *distanceFilterValue*.

Here's the implementation of my config view controller:

```
@interface SimpleConfigViewController()
//private interface inside implementation
@property (weak, nonatomic) UISlider * distanceFilterSlider;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *distanceFilterValue;
@end

@implementation SimpleConfigViewController

@synthesize distanceFilterLabel = _distanceFilterLabel;
@synthesize distanceFilterSlider = _distanceFilterSlider;
@synthesize distanceFilterValue = _distanceFilterValue;

- (NSNumber *)distanceFilterValue {
    if (!_distanceFilterValue) {
        _distanceFilterValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:250.0];
    }
    return _distanceFilterValue;
}

- (IBAction)distanceSliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    self.distanceFilterValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:sender.value];
    //update GUI
    self.distanceFilterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f m", sender.value];
}


@end
```

It seems to me that because I keep a strong pointer to distanceFilterValue, this value should be correct when I return back to config view. I'm clearly missing something here.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What would be relevant is the implementation of the map view.

Comment: Well I'm trying to get the config view working independent of the map view before I actually begin wiring the configuration values to the map view.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I guess the config view is unloaded, and loaded again from the `XIB` when it's pushed the second time.

You should store your values in a model object anyway and not in a controller!

Comment: I've placed to log messages to test this and i've found that upon the first load of config view *viewDidLoad* is called. But upon returning to the Map view *viedDidUnload* is not called.

Comment: I realize that I *should* put distanceFilterValue in a model object but doesn't keeping a strong pointer to an NSNumber object achieve the same effect? My model would simple be a wrapper class for which I would keep a strong pointer to. (This is my thought process, I could very well be wrong in this assumption)

Answer (score 0):

I think that Erik is right, everytime you call viewDidLoad for your configView it will reset. You could use a Singleton or NSUserDefaults to solve this.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is at what point (and why) is my strong pointer to distanceFilterValue is *released*?

Comment: What's in the viewDidLoad in your configView?

Comment: Just the standard [super viewDidLoad];